# Can I assign a copy of an array of objects and add to those objects at the same time?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Say I have an array of objects:

```
const myArr = [
    {name: 'one'},
    {name: 'two'}
]
```

If I wanted to use this array of object as a base and add a custom property to the objects for each use case I might have, could I assign the array to a new variable and also change the contents of its objects at the same time?

I know this can be done in 2 steps, but I'm wondering if it's possible to do it all at once?

For example:

```
const copyArr = myArr;
copyArr.forEach(obj => obj.newProp = 'some-new-prop');
```

This would now be

```
[
    {name: 'one', newProp: 'some-new-prop'},
    {name: 'two', newProp: 'some-new-prop'}
]
```

Comment: look at array.prototype.map. It creates a new array where each item in the array is the return value of the callback function (like forEach but with return)

Comment: Note that assigning an array to a new variable does not copy the content. It just re-assigns a pointer to the same instance. At least for arrays and objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over each item and modify them.
Note that `map` will not modify your original array and therefore is immutable.

```js
const myArr = [{ name: "one" }, { name: "two" }];

const copyArr = myArr.map((item) => ({
  ...item,
  newProps: "some-new-prop",
}));

// [ { name: 'one', newProps: 'some-new-prop' },
//   { name: 'two', newProps: 'some-new-prop' } ]
```